# How do I find out if games or apps support 3D on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, stereo-3d

So I got a 3D TV and an Xbox One. So far I didn't recognize any 3D capabilities in Dead Rising 3 and FIFA 14. How do I tell if the game or app supports it? For me it's especially interesting if 3D split screen gaming works.

How can I test the 3D gaming possibilities on the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Xbox One games to date support 3D and the feature has not been announces as of now. As there is no support, there is also no way to test 3D capabilities.

Comment: Any support that did exist would be on the game case. An example of this is the Green Latern Xbox 360/PS3 game that was released.

Answer (score -1):

Xbox One got Xbox 360 backward compatibility in 2015, so check out the previous generation's [3D supported game list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_360_games_with_3D_support) and stay tuned.

*I wonder why Minecraft don't get it, i really liked that feature in the PC version ...*

Comment: But does the console support the 3D? If the game has it, but the console has not got it turned on, yet, the games still not going to have it

Comment: Most TV's, games use passive 3D, and supporting that is just an illusion. Supporting active 3D is depending on the HDMI version, and both console have HDMI 1.4, so yes, they are.

Comment: @Timelord64 BTW downvoting by your own ignorance is bad, i would gladly extend my answer to make it more helpful or clear if you ask it in a comment.

Comment: Maybe so, @Tuss, but your only now bringing my attention to it. You can not change your vote on a question that has not changed this long after voting. Also, I downvoted for the commentary, as I was already unsure about the 3D. Since this is a "check and see if that works. stay tuned for the real answer", I feel this is better as a comment, but not as an answer.

Comment: @Timelord64 `How do I find out if games or apps support 3D on Xbox One?` was the question and i posted an answer with a list of the few, soon available 100%  3D supported games. i cant see how this could be just a comment ...